# "X increases with Y"

Tags: expressions, ambiguity

I wonder how do native speakers interpret the following sentences. Are they ambiguous? Is Y decreasing or increasing in the following examples (1-4)?

1. *The strength of X increases with Y.*
2. *The strength of X decreases with Y.*
3. *The strength of X increases together with Y.*
4. *The strength of X decreases together with Y.*

I think it is possible to make these sentences unambiguous by specifying whether Y is increasing or decreasing explicitly after “with”. Is that so?

(Does adding "together" (or jointly) like in sentences (3-4) change interpretation?)

Thanks!

Comment: Lose the _together_. It adds nothing and is potentially confusing.

Comment: The “with” is causing your concerns. *The strength of X increases as Y increases.*

Comment: I think you should avoid the terminology unless it's a part of the jargon associated with the specific technology being discussed.

Comment: Try one of: The strength of X is proportional to Y. The strength of X is inversely proportional to Y.  Depending on the nature of their relationship.

Comment: This is mathematics, and 'X increases with Y' is standard language. Of course if X increases with Y, then X increases *in some proportion* as Y increases. They would thus decrease together. For an inverse relationship (like X divided by Y), X *decreases* as Y increases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd interpret:

*1. The strength of X increases with Y.*

alternate way of saying: The strength of X increases with Y increasing.

*2. The strength of X decreases with Y.*

This one to me is a bit vague. The way I read it is: The strength of X decreases with Y increasing.  In other words they're inversely proportional.  But it could also mean the opposite and needs to be fixed so it's not vague.

*3. The strength of X increases together with Y.*

alternate way of saying: The strength of X increases together with Y increasing. In other words, they both go up together as either one increases.

*4. The strength of X decreases together with Y.*

alternate way of saying:  The strength of X decreases together with Y decreasing.  In other words, they both decrease together as either decreases.  For me at least, the 'together' makes this one different from number 2. above.

For me, 2. and 4. are vague and could benefit from more specific language.  I'm pretty confident most all readers would understand the meaning of 1. and 3.

Comment: The problem is that none of the sentences are clear as there is absolutely no context. We do not know if X and Y are both variables, independents, or one is a dependant of the other.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentences all read fairly easily, and they mean the same thing. They mean

**The strength of X is directly proportional to Y.**

This means the strength of X increases when Y increases, decreasing when Y does the same. The opposite would be *The strength of X is inversely proportional to Y.*

Comment: Direct proportionality is a much stricter condition than "increases with"